# How to prove a permutation is odd?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a part of a long proof:

Let $G$ be a group of order $2m$ where $m$ is odd. Let $G$ acts on itself by group operation. Let $f:G \rightarrow Sym(G)$ be the associated homomorphism. i.e. f(g) = $\pi_g$.

By Cauchy's theorem, there exists an element $g \in G$ with $|g|=2$. 
By Cayley's theorem, $f(G)=Im(f)\cong G$. Then $f(g)=\pi_g$ and $|\pi_g|=2$.

I do not understand the very next step:

" $\pi_g$ is the product of $m$ disjoint 2-cycles." Can someone please explain this in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cayley's Theorem, $\pi_g$ is a product of $|G|/|g|$ cycles of length $|g|$.
This can be proven by considering the orbit of each element in $\pi_g$.

Comment: Right, but how do you know that $n=m=\frac{|G|}{2}$? Every $2$-cycle has order $2$ and so I don't see why $\pi_g$ can't just be a single $2$-cycle.

Comment: @StellaBiderman The element $\pi_g$ corresponds to the left multiplication action of $g$ on $G$. If it were merely a $2$-cycle that would imply that it fixes all but two elements of $G$. But unless $g$ is the identity of $G$, left multiplication by it cannot fix *any* element of the group.

Comment: @Stella Biderman -- Since $g$ is not the identity, the permutation $\pi_g$ doesn't fix any elements of $G$. Hence the disjoint cycle representation of $\pi_g$ must "cover" all $2m$ elements. Since $\pi_g$ has order $2$, it follows that all of the disjoint cycles are $2$-cycles, hence there must be exactly $m$ of them.

Comment: @john ah yes, that makes perfect sense. I forgot to consider the context of the action.

Comment: @StellaBiderman yea! Pretty neat little result really, right?

Comment: Thus, if $g \in G$ has order $k$ say, the disjoint cycle representation of $\pi_g$ must consist only of $k$-cycles (and no fixed points, unless $g$ is the identity), which gives an immediate proof (with invoking Lagrange's Theorem) that the order of $g$ divides the order of $G$.